# EE Matrix Ajax Pagination

Tags: matrix, pagination, ajax

hey i'm running through a serious problem , i found a lot of answers about this topic nothing really helped, theres no direct obvious answer

> heres a PHP page that i want to do with EE matrix+jQuery instead of
>   PHP+mySQL+jQuery: http://egyptianartsgroup.com/videos.php
>   look at "Featured Videos" section

and this is my code for just looping the matrix , outputting the featured items for isotope blocking

```
<div id="container" class="photos clearfix variable-sizes">
   {exp:channel:entries channel="featured" url_title="main-featured" limit="1"}
   {featured_items search:active="Yes" sort="asc" limit="5"}
   {if type == "Video"}
      <div class="photo video">
         {thumb_image}
        <img src="{path}_thumbnails/{filename}.{extension}" />
        {/thumb_image}
        <a href="{vlink}" class="featuredVideoIcon" t = "video" title="{overlayed_title}"></a>
        <a href="{vlink}" class="FeaturedTitleLink" t = "video" title="{overlayed_title}"><h2 class="FeaturedTitle">{overlayed_title} </h2></a>
        </div>
   {if:else}
   <div class="photo image">
            {thumb_image}
            <img src="{path}_thumbnails/{filename}.{extension}" />
            {/thumb_image}
            <a  class="featuredEnlargIcon" href= "{thumb_image}" title="{overlayed_title}" t = "image"></a>
            <a  class="FeaturedTitleLink" href= "{thumb_image}" t = "image" title="{overlayed_title}"><h2 class="FeaturedTitle">{overlayed_title} -- {row_count} of / {total_rows}</h2></a>
            </div>
   {/if}

   {/featured_items}

   {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

any ideas to ajax paginate the matrix entries for isotope ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create pagination using a combination of the `{matrix_field_name:total_rows}` variable, the `limit=xx` and `offset=xx` parameters to the Matrix tag pair and a math plugin such as [MX Calculator](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-calculator).

An example of this method was posted on [EE Insider](http://eeinsider.com/tips/view/javascript-pagination-with-matrix-mx-calc-and-jquery/) some time back.